# How can I round only 2 corners of a button in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button

I have a button that is rounded in all four corners since I used the User Defined Runtime Attributes panel to make it rounded... but once running the application I saw that the button would be better off if only the right side was rounded and the left side was just squared. Is there a way I can do this? I am using Xcode 9.1 and Swift 4.

Comment: you need to use UIBezierPath API provided by smart apple engineers. Create a class as subclass of UIButton, in storyboard give your button that class. Then in draw method make your design.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is

```
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.testButton.bounds, byRoundingCorners:[.topRight, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = self.testButton.bounds
    maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
    self.yourButton.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

O/P will look like

[image]

You said

> I saw that the button would be better off if only the right side was
>   rounded and the left side was just squared

Did not mention clearly is both top and bottom right corner will be rounded or not so I took a liberty to imagine the same. You can choose whatever you want by modifying

```
[.topRight, .bottomRight]
```

value I specified in code above